# Tampermonkey - Can't call own functions in button onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, greasemonkey, tampermonkey

I try to code a test script for the [Unity Documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/). 
Basically I try to add a div with some test controls (Alert A, B, C and a close Button).

[image]

[image]

If the user rights click on a link element in the **scroll list at left**, then the default context menue should not show, instead my div should spawn.

I already solved this. The box in the following screenshot spawned after right clicking on the link "Scriptable render pipeline".

[image]

However, the buttons do not work as expected. Each button should show a simple javascript alert and each uses a different approach to do so.

---

**Problem 1:** If I press an alert button from the div **for the first time**, then the list ALWAYS scrolls to the top again and the function is not executed. It does not scroll to the top if I press on the `X` (close button).

**Problem 2:** No button except of "Alert B" works at all.
UPDATE: I tried it again today without changing anything in the code, and now "Alert A" is spawning?! But sometimes it does not spawn, I have to wait a bit before I click, seems like it need some time to initialize?

---

**Alert A**

UPDATE: I tried it again today without changing anything in the code, and now "Alert A" is spawning perfectly fine?!

This method does not work at all, nothing happens, there is also no warning or error.

```
<button id="A" class="A"> AlertA </button>

...

$("div.mCSB_container").delegate("#A", "click", function() {
    alert("Hello from Alert A");
});
```

**Alert B (WORKS)**

This alert works, but also only after the second click, it scrolls the list to the top on EACH click for unknown reasons.

```
<button id="B" onclick="alert('Hello from B')"> AlertB </button>
```

[image]

**Alert C**

I get `Uncaught ReferenceError: AlertC is not defined`.

```
<button id="C" onclick="AlertC()"> AlertC </button>

...

function AlertC()
{
    alert("Hello from C");
}
```

**Close Button**

This method does not work at all, nothing happens, there is also no warning or error.

```
$(".confirmBoxClose").on("click", function(e) {
    alert("Removing this box");
    $(".confirmBox").remove();
});
```

This is my full tampermonkey script:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Unity Documentation
// @namespace    https://docs.unity3d.com
// @version      1.0
// @description  test
// @author       Edward Black
// @match        *://docs.unity3d.com/*
// @grant        GM_addStyle
// ==/UserScript==

GM_addStyle('.confirmBox { z-index: 100; width: 275px; background-color: greenyellow; border: 1px solid black; }');
GM_addStyle('.confirmBoxButtons { margin-top: 5px; }');
GM_addStyle('.confirmBoxClose { position: absolute; height: 20px; width: 20px; background-color: white; color:black; border: 0.5px solid black; text-align: center; right: 0px; }');
GM_addStyle('.confirmBoxClose:hover { background-color: black; color:white; cursor: pointer; }');

$(document).ready(function() {

    setTimeout(function() {
        run();
    }, 4000);

});

function run()
{
        $("div.mCSB_container").find("a").each(function(j, obj) {

            $(obj).on("contextmenu", function(){
                return false;
            });

                $(obj).on("mousedown", function(e){
                    if( e.button == 2 ) {

                        console.log('Right mouse button!');
                        showConfirmBox(this);

                        return false;
                    }
                    return true;
                });
        });
}

function showConfirmBox(container)
{
    $(".confirmBox").remove();

    var elm = '<li><div class="confirmBox">'+
                  '<div class="confirmBoxClose">x</div>' +

                  '<div class="confirmBoxButtons">' +
                      '<button id="A"> AlertA </button>' +
                      '<button id="B" onclick="alert(\'Hello from B\')"> AlertB (works) </button>' +
                      '<button id="C" onclick="AlertC()"> AlertC </button>' +
                  '</div>' +
              '</div></li>';

    $parent = $(container).parent();
    $(elm).appendTo($parent);
}

$("div.mCSB_container").delegate("#A", "click", function() {
    alert("Hello from A");
});

function AlertC()
{
    alert("Hello from C");
}

$("div.mCSB_container").delegate(".confirmBoxClose", "click", function() {
    $(".confirmBox").remove();
});
```

B is the only Method that works, but I need to call a function instead, because I try to run alot more code after the button was clicked.

**Questions:**

- Why does the list always scrolls to the top after a button click?
- Why It does not also scroll to the top if I press on the `X` (close button)?
- Why is only "Alert C" working?

Comment: Is this question solved?  It looks to be a near duplicate to [your later one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47392322/html-click-on-button-causes-list-to-scroll-on-top-for-unknown-reasons).

Comment: Yes, it is solved, but I can accept my answer only in 4 hours. I asked the other question to find out why `<button>` behaves differently than `<div>` I think I just asked too many questions at once at this one.

Answer (score 0):

I found the reaon why the click on a button was not always detected. I had to move the EventListeners to the `setTimeout` function of `$(document).ready()`, because the scroll list was loaded asynchronously after the document.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    setTimeout(function() {
        run();
        $("div.mCSB_container").delegate("#A", "click", function() {
            alert("Hello from A");
        });
        $("div.mCSB_container").delegate(".confirmBoxClose", "click", function() {
            $(".confirmBox").remove();
        });
    }, 4000);
});
```

I am not sure why, but I had to replace `<button>` with `<div>`, this solved the problem with the list scrolling to the top at a button click and now I only have to press the button once.

```
var elm = '<li><div class="confirmBox">'+
              '<div class="confirmBoxClose">x</div>' +

              '<div class="confirmBoxButtons">' +
                  '<div id="A"> AlertA </div>' +
                  '<div id="B" onclick="alert(\'Hello from B\')"> AlertB (works) </div>' +
                  '<div id="C" onclick="AlertC()"> AlertC </div>' +
              '</div>' +
          '</div></li>';
```

I am totally unsure why this does only happen with `<button>` and not with `<div>`, I will ask another question for this specific problem to find out wheter this is normal or a html bug.

And `AlertC()` does not work at all, I have to define the script directly after spawning the button to make it work:

```
...

'<div id="C" class="confirmBoxBtn" onclick="AlertC()"> AlertC </div>' +
'<script>function AlertC() { alert("Hello from C"); }</script>' +

...
```