# HTML - Click on button causes list to scroll on top for unknown reasons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, greasemonkey, tampermonkey

I am using tampermonkey to add some custom buttons to the [Unity Documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual).

I noticed a strange problem If I am using a html `<button>`. Everytime when I click on the button, then the scroll list is scrolling to the top and the code is only executed on the second click.

---

**However, If I replace `<button>` with `<div>` then everything is working perfectly fine.**

---

Why is `<button>` behaving so weird?

Below is the `tampermonkey` script for reproduction.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Unity Documentation (bugtest)
// @namespace    https://docs.unity3d.com
// @version      1.0
// @description  test
// @author       Edward Black
// @match        *://docs.unity3d.com/*
// @grant        GM_addStyle
// ==/UserScript==

GM_addStyle('.confirmBox { z-index: 100; width: 275px; background-color: greenyellow; border: 1px solid black; }');
GM_addStyle('.confirmBoxButtons { margin-top: 5px; }');
GM_addStyle('.confirmBoxClose { position: absolute; height: 20px; width: 20px; background-color: white; color:black; border: 0.5px solid black; text-align: center; right: 0px; }');
GM_addStyle('.confirmBoxClose:hover { background-color: black; color:white; cursor: pointer; }');
GM_addStyle('.confirmBoxBtn { background-color: white; color:black; width: 100px; border: 1px solid black; }');
GM_addStyle('.confirmBoxBtn:hover { background-color: black; color:white; cursor: pointer; }');

$(document).ready(function() {

    setTimeout(function() {
        prepareCustomContextMenue();
        $("div.mCSB_container").delegate("#theButton", "click", function() {
            alert("Hello from Button");
        });
        $("div.mCSB_container").delegate("#theDiv", "click", function() {
            alert("Hello from Div");
        });
        $("div.mCSB_container").delegate(".confirmBoxClose", "click", function() {
            $(".confirmBox").remove();
        });

    }, 4000);


});

function prepareCustomContextMenue()
{
    $("div.mCSB_container").find("a").each(function(j, obj) {

        $(obj).on("contextmenu", function(){
            return false;
        });
        $(obj).on("mousedown", function(e){
            if( e.button == 2 ) {

                console.log('Right mouse button!');
                showConfirmBox(this);

                return false;
            }
            return true;
        });
    });
}

function showConfirmBox(container)
{
    $(".confirmBox").remove();

    var elm = '<li><div class="confirmBox">'+
                  '<div class="confirmBoxClose">x</div>' +

                  '<div class="confirmBoxButtons">' +
                      '<button id="theButton" class="confirmBoxBtn"> This is a button </button>' +
                      '<div id="theDiv" class="confirmBoxBtn"> This is a div </div>' +
                  '</div>' +
              '</div></li>';

    $parent = $(container).parent();
    $(elm).appendTo($parent);
}
```

---

### Instructions

---

Wait until the site loaded completly (about 4 seconds until the site load indicator disapeared) then **right click** on a link in the scroll list at left, which should be as far as possible down (so you can see that the list is actually scrolling up after clicking on the button).
Now a container should appear:

[image]

Now click on the `<button>` named `This is a button` and notice that the scroll list scrolls to the top and the code from the button is not executed (alert should show). Press again on the button and notice that the code is now executed and the scroll list scrolls to top again after pressing Ok on the alert.

Next click on the `<div>` named `This is a div` and note that everything works as expected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several issues with that script and, as Jim-miraidev pointed out, you need to use jQuery's `.on()`, `.stopPropagation()`, and `.preventDefault()`.

But the priority problem here is that **the page has several other events at play** (especially `click` and `mouseup`). The userscript code is causing the page's flexbox scroll state to get confused.
<sub>(Exhibit A: the scroll only happens on first click immediately after the `mousedown` event that fires `showConfirmBox()`.)</sub>

So, an easy way to patch this is to **capture all 3 of the (potentially) conflicting events**:

```
$("div.mCSB_container").on ("click mousedown mouseup", "#theButton", function (zEvent) {
    zEvent.preventDefault ();
    zEvent.stopPropagation ();

    if (zEvent.type == "mousedown") {
        console.log ("Hello from Button");
    }
} );
```

---

Note that browsers fire the events in the order: mousedown, mouseup, click.

Comment: But I still wonder why it works with a `<div>` without problems.
Ah so thats how to use `on()`, i thought it works like @Jim-miraidev`posted it. Thanks!

Comment: Jim-miraidev's code is valid, but it doesn't address the question problem.  Also, it's not a good approach for elements that are getting deleted all the time (which is another issue with the script).  As for the div thing, open another question if you must, but there are a few things going on and I don't want to poke into it right now.

Answer (score 1):

Buttons default will submit the page, causing a refresh.

```
<button id="theButton" class="confirmBoxBtn"> This is a button </button>
```

The default  "type" for a button is "submit", which self posts. Update the button "type" to "button".

```
<button type="button" id="theButton" class="confirmBoxBtn"> This is a button </button>
```

Also delagate() as of jQuery 3.0, has been deprecated. Update for

```
 $("#theButton").on("click", function(e) {
      // remove default of the click
      e.preventDefault();
      // stop propagation
      e.stopPropagation();
     alert("Hello from Button");
 });
```

Comment: You may need to stop propagation as well

Comment: I can't seem to see the issue you are having. Is the page above the one you are updating?